# Trouble adding custom methods to spring jap repositories

Tags: java, spring, repository

I got my Spring JPA repositories working but i cannot create custom methods with in it like following is my simple repository

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<JPA_Users, Long> {

    List<JPA_Users> findByName(String Name);

}
```

then within my controller class i declare variable 
CrudRepository repository;

and got it instantiated

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans1.xml"); 
repository = context.getBean(UserRepository.class);
```

Now i was expecting that i can have that by using    repository.findByName    and i don't find that

on the i am going through many articles they want service and then its implementation and then they do the autowiring     i don't get any of that ideas.      please guide me declaring a custom JPA repository method

Note that i have XML where jpaVendorAdapter   EntityManagerFactory etc are declared and working as expected   i have simple repository through i can do CRUD

Shahzad

Comment: Please don't tell me you are actually creating an instance of the context again to retrieve a dependency? Unless you want strange memory, transaction, concurrency issues that is the way to go, otherwise use dependency injection.

Comment: You need to declare the variable like UserRepository repository not as CrudRepository repository. And as M. Deinum mentioned, you need to create only one context having all your beans - repositories, controllers and whatever else you need (as opposed to creating the context in within your controler).

Comment: Michal thanks for pointing out my mistake  User Repository worked and now the object has findByName function

But now i have some more problems 

notice i declare function in repository as 

List<JPA_Users> findByName(String Name); 



I made the following call 

Iterable usrs = repository.findByName("shahzad");

and i was expecting that a list of records will be return.    I have multiple records with Shahzad name column 


M.Deinum i am a bit new in spring and java and usually i just follow step by step instructions    can you please give me more education

Comment: For your 2nd question, can you also paste the JPA_Users class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you already wire the beans1.xml to your application context, then declare the repository in your controller as following:

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository repository;
```

Otherwise in your code sample, you should declare your "repository" variable as an instance of UserRepository:

```
UserRepository repository = (UserRepository) context.getBean(UserRepository.class);
```

Because if you declare it as CrudRepository, the parent class can be successfully casted but lost the signature of your interface.

Comment: Yes i got it    but  i have another problem that i wrote in above comments against two comments.   can you please comment on that well      thanks in advance  :)

Comment: I see. Can you paste the code also, I'm little bit confused about what's your next question is?

Comment: LynxZh autowired is getting a bit confused for me as well.   I have MVC application and in my controller function RequestMapping to a URL  i am creating the application context as   ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans1.xml");    i cannot declare Autowired within the RequestMapping function      where should i declare autowired variable.    i tried to declare it under class declaration but that gave error.   please guide

Comment: By default the application context is created during spring application load up and from the webcontext initialization. If you are creating the applicationcontext base on your own beans1.xml then it just exists in the context of your controller. So in that case you will not get it autowired because the autowire context in the controller is using the webcontext. You can just use the #2 way to do it.

Comment: Please see my comment, please paste the JPA_Users as well.

Comment: ok i added another question    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37859163/this-spring-data-query-is-not-working

Answer (score 0):

LynxZh my code is simple  i have repository as

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<JPA_Users, Long> {

    List<JPA_Users> findByName(String Name);

}
```

then i have a controller class with following Request Mapped function

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/jpadata1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String jpadata1(ModelMap map) {        
        UserRepository repository;


        //Remember     beans1.xml is located in src/main/resources   folder    but 
        //load with just beans1.xml
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans1.xml"); 
        repository = context.getBean(UserRepository.class);
```

you can see i have my repository then i called following function

Iterable usrs = repository.findByName("jpa data");

and expecting all records with name shahzad will be return    but it return no record

Comment: You can edit your original question and put those below your original one.