# This spring data query is not working

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, data-access

Here is my UserRepository and a find function

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<JPA_Users, Long> {

    List<JPA_Users> findByName(String Name);

}
```

then in one of the controller function i try to access this find function as follows

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/jpadata1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String jpadata1(ModelMap map) {        
        UserRepository repository;


        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans1.xml"); 
        repository = context.getBean(UserRepository.class);


        Iterable usrs = repository.findByName("shahzad");

}
```

there is a column with named  name  in database and i have multiple records with values   shahzad         i was expecting that all those records will be return but this function returns nothing    no records are return

Shahzad

Comment: Frankly, you really need to get back to the basics and learn the basic concepts behing Spring: what is a context, what is dependency injection, etc. Re-creating a new context from a Spring bean to then lookup a repository from this new context is completely wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans1.xml"); 
    repository = context.getBean(UserRepository.class);
```

You are creating a new context with each request, which is a really wrong strategy.

As a first correction, don't create a new Context in your Controller, you should use dependency injection.

```
@Autorwired
private UserRepository userRepository; 
@RequestMapping(value = "/jpadata1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String jpadata1(ModelMap map) {        
    Iterable usrs = userRepository.findByName("shahzad");
}
```

Comment: yes thanks for advise, new to spring and really this is what i found that i am doing a horrible thing with ApplicationContext and going through the basics.  Thanks guys for pointing this out.    But can you please answer my original question why i am not getting records ?

Comment: There could be a lot of reasons, maybe you want to publish your project on github?

Answer (score 0):

Go to **JPA_Users** class and if you are using ***eclipse*** as ide then type outline and check what is the **getter value** for the field **name/Name** what ever you have in pojo class.

In Repository layer try this below annotation also:

```
org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
@Transactional
```

As well as check yours pojo class **primary id** is of type **Long** or not.